# Назначить ключи массива из переменной. PHP

Tags: php

Мне необходимо создать массив с ключами и значениями из пременных.
Код примерно такой

```
$col = array();
$c=1;
foreach($d->COLSPEC as $colspec){
  $col[$colspec] = $c;
  echo "$colspec/$c:{$col[$colspec]}<br>";
  $c++;
}
var_dump($col);
```

переменные $colspec $c выводит в норме, а массив $col пустой.

Проверил вот так работает нормально.

```
$col = array();
$key = "x";
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
  $col[$key]=$i;
  $key .= "x";
}
var_dump($col);
```

Что не так?

Comment: Приложите примеры содержимого  $colspec $c

Comment: "col1/1: col2/2: col4/3:" но в массив ключ 'col1' и значение '1' не добавляет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример решения. Скорее всего вы неверно разыменовываете структуру $d, но поскольку она неизвестна, то невозможно сказать более определенно.

```
$array = array("col1" => 1,  
              "col2" => 2, 
              "col3" => 3
              );

$col = array();

foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
    $col[$key]=$value;
}

print_r($col);
```

Comment: Да,  заранее не известно $d, но значние для ключа выводит всегда (echo для проверки). Хм...  если только там не String,  а какой то объект.  И в выводе echo он просто преобразует в String,  а в ключь не понимае

Comment: @Freqnsy добавьте явное приведение к `$col[(striing)$colspec] = ..` да проверьте, ну или `var_dump` вместо `echo`, там и тип данных покажет

Comment: ВОПРОС РЕШЕН. В переменной было: object(SimpleXMLElement)#51 (1) {[0]=>string(4) "col2"} . Явное приведение решило проблему. echo автоматом приводил в string, а ключ не принимало. Всем спасибо.